# When can I save the edits of the questions again?

Tags: support

I edited several of my old questions and pressed the button "save edits". Then I found the box "Too many recent edits".

When can I edit the questions again?

Comment: As far as I know there is a limit of 5 posts you can edit a day (except recent posts) to prevent vandalism of your own posts. Here's [a more detailed explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91097/getting-too-many-edits-further-edits-are-not-allowed-until-tomorrow). I would try right now, since it's a new UTC day. Else, you'll have to wait until a moderator drops by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Theo noted, we limit edits on old posts due to incidences of self-vandalism (mostly ragequitting).

[Getting "Too many edits [...] Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91097/getting-too-many-edits-further-edits-are-not-allowed-until-tomorrow)

The limit is 5 edits on your *old* posts per day.

Answer (score 1):

I felt this didn't warrant being another "topic", so I'll post this here.

After thinking a bit about the limits on editing old posts, I thought it funny that I can keep editing posts of other people, but I'm limited to just five edits on my own posts.

Now, if my experience with forum moderation counts for anything, most instances of auto-vandalism associated with "ragequitting" I've seen is more often than not either of 1) deletion, or 2) replacement. I don't think I've ever seen a auto-vandal append stuff to an old post (except probably a spammer).

"Quite dandy, J.M.; now what's your point?" I'm thinking that if (yes I know, that's a big "if") the performance penalty is not too much, how about having the software [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) an edit and the old version, and retaining the edit limit for replacements and deletions, but relaxing the restriction a bit for additions?

Besides, since we have a good pool of users with edit privileges, a vandalized post won't stay vandalized for long before being reverted, yes?

Comment: I think the more relevant point is that 99% of the time most users need neither know nor care that this limit even *exists*...